# Why using Bootstrap Glyphicons in CSS with large padding causing unwanted icons showing up?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know how to display an icon as such:

```
<span class='icon-remove'></span>
```

But If I add `padding` to the `span`, extra icon shows up. How to fix it?

```
span {
    padding-right:60px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqVvA/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glyphs are presented using one large image map (or so called CSS sprites), so if you leave enough space on in either side of the element it will show other glyphs as well. Two solutions comes to mind:

1) Put the icon in a containing element:

```
<span><i class='icon-remove'></i></span>
```

2) Or use margin:

```
span { margin-right: 60px }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure you just want to have some whitespace to the right of the icon? Have you tried `margin`:

```
<span class='icon-remove' style='margin-right:60px'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason extra padding displays more icons is that Bootstrap uses CSS sprites to display icons. What you're actually seeing is a background image, more specifically a section of a large background image that includes many available icons. The definition of the class "icon-remove" specifies the background-position property to select the particular icon. If you add padding, you will reveal more of the background image, which will show additional icons.

The solution, then, is to either add margin, as Rid Iculous suggested, or couch your  within another element and add padding to that. I'd go with the margin.